# There is an incompatible JNA native library installed on this system

Tags: java, jna, tess4j

Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djna.nosys=true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:

There is an incompatible JNA native library installed on this system
Expected: TEMPLATE
Found:    7.0.0
(at C:\Users******\AppData\Local\Temp\jna--1969139829\jna11608139008886810060.dll).
To resolve this issue you may do one of the following:

- remove or uninstall the offending library
- set the system property jna.nosys=true
- set jna.boot.library.path to include the path to the version of the
  jnidispatch library included with the JNA jar file you are using

  at com.sun.jna.Native.(Native.java:225)
  at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:83)
  at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.(TessAPI.java:42)
  at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:379)
  at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:292)
  at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:275)
  at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:256)
  at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:240)
  at javatap.score.main(score.java:38)

It was working fine till i messed with a few .dlls.
I don't know what is wrong.

I tried _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Djna.nosys=true and changing the dlls back to the original ones. But nothing seems to work.

Comment: The "Expected: TEMPLATE" implies you're using a JNA jar compiled from source without using the actual build system.  Download and use the JAR from maven or properly build on your system using `ant`.

Comment: RE: "It was working fine till i messed with a few .dlls. I don't know what is wrong."  Don't mess with the DLLs.  Or tell us which ones you messed with.